# converting html to pdf

Tags: javascript, css, linux, pdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf from linux ,also i have to use this in web APP please let me know  what tools are available for this.Please let me know any other tools for this

So far i have tried

```
    html2ps htmlfilename > a.ps
    ps2pdf a.ps > a.pdf
```

But the above doesnt convert images and is ignoring css .My Development environment is linux(RHEL5)

Also i have tried http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/convert-html-to-pdf-linux.html i get this error

```
  [root@localhost bin]# ./wkhtmltopdf www.example.com a.pdf
  ./wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` is *by far* the best choice you have. Make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right path: [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is the easiest way to do this. Note that the code in the repositories might be outdated (not sure how up-to date this package is); you may need to compile it from source, or get the statically-linked version (which is huge, but has the QT library and other dependencies already included).

Also, in your case, you may just be missing a library - installing `libqt4-webkit-dev` might do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that are easy to implement and suitable to convert HTML+CSS to pdf are.

1) **Using "Jspdf javascript" plugin with "html2canvas plugin" (Web App).**

- Insert stable version of jspdf plugin.

  `var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src ='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.min.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);`
- Insert html2canvas plugin

  `var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);`
- Insert the following script

  `var html2obj = html2canvas($('your div class here'));
  var queue  = html2obj.parse();
  var canvas = html2obj.render(queue);

  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  console.log(img);

  var doc=new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
  var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;

  var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
  doc.addImage(canvas, 'JPEG',  15, 35, 180, 240,'SLOW');
  doc.save("save.pdf");`
- Special Case for IE 11

  `document.getElementById("your div here").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";`

2)  **Using wkhtmltopdf**

- Install wkhtmltopdf from [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
- we can directly use wkhtmltopdf from terminal/commandLine , However in case of java language we have a [wrapper](https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper) which we can use.
- Code Example using wkhtmltopdf wrapper

  `import com.github.jhonnymertz.wkhtmltopdf.wrapper.Pdf;
  import com.github.jhonnymertz.wkhtmltopdf.wrapper.page.PageType;
  import com.github.jhonnymertz.wkhtmltopdf.wrapper.params.Param;
  public class PofPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

  @Override
  public void render(RenderRequest request , RenderResponse response) throws PortletException , IOException

  { super.render(request, response);
  Pdf pdf = new Pdf();

  pdf.addPage("http://www.google.com", PageType.url);
  // Add a Table of contents
  pdf.addToc();
  // The "wkhtmltopdf" shell command accepts different types of options such as global, page, headers and footers, and toc. Please see "wkhtmltopdf -H" for a full explanation.
  // All options are passed as array, for example:
  // Save the PDF
  try {
  pdf.saveAs("E:\\output.pdf");
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }`

3) Other tools include phantom.js , itextpdf , grabz.it

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest way would be to launch any modern browser, go to the site, and then use the browser's "print" capability to print to a pdf (assuming your system has a pdf printer set up). I don't know if that's an option in your case, though, and this sort of thing won't work from within a web app. Still, you may want to try it.

Comment: Ya but whats the point of this answer i have clearly mentioned that i want this in my web APP..

Comment: This might actually be a useful way - if you outsource this to the mechanical turk or a similar service (where you can submit menial tasks automatically, and there are people on the other side doing that work, IIRC). It would cost a few cents for every screenshot though, and most likely there would be significant latency.

Comment: @rajeev - *shrug* I mentioned in my answer that it's not going to work from the web app, and that it was just another way to convert html to pdf. That being said, there are probably quite a few ways to set up a script that would simply have firefox a web page and print it to pdf.